# intellij internal webserver using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, intellij-idea

IntelliJ 14 has a built-in Webserver where you can run html-files on localhost port 63342.
Is there any possibility to use rewrite rules (like modrewrite) within a .htaccess file or something similar?

Or do I have to install a local webserver for this?

Regards,
Jens